# jQuery DataTables loading a client-side array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the .data() function in jQuery to attach a set of records, returned from the server, to a DOM element on my page.  The records are stored as an array of Objects.  The code is as follows:

```
    //Attached returned data to an HTML table element
    $('#measTable').data('resultSet', resultSet);

    //Get stored data from HTML table element
var results = $('#measTable').data('resultSet');

//Construct the measurement table
data_table = $('#measTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "aaData": [ results ],
    "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "Field1" },
                { "mDataProp": "Field2" },
                { "mDataProp": "Field3" },
                { "mDataProp": "Field4" }
            ]
});
```

I then fetch the data from the element and proceed to load it into the datatable.  But this doens't seem to work and always returns with the error **Requested unknown parameter "`Field1" from the data source at row 0**. Is it possible to load data into datatables in this manner?

UPDATE:

Here is a sample of the result object array

```
results = 
    0: Object
       Field1: "2011/04/23"
       Field2: 8
       Field3: "Hello"
       Field4: "World"
       __proto__: Object
    1: Object
       Field1: "2011/03/25"
       Field2: 6
       Field3: "Hello"
       Field4: "Everyone"
       __proto__: Object
...etc.
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of 'results'?

Comment: Hi Adam, just posted a code snippet of the result object array.

Comment: The DataTables blog has a [post](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Extended_data_source_options_with_DataTables) on this. Are you using 1.8? This definitely won't work in earlier versions.

Answer (score 5):

Allan, the developer of DataTables, was able to answer my question in the following post in the DataTables [forum](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/22689#Comment_22689).  In case the link doesn't work, the issue turned out to be a simple syntax error.

Instead of `"aaData": [ results ],` it needs to be `"aaData": results,`.

Thank you for your help Allan.

Answer (score 1):

Well, aaData (as it name suggests using [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)) expects an array of arrays, so if you fetch him an array of objects that is why it complains.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your definition the following:

```
$('#measTable').dataTable({
    ...
    "columns": [
        { "data": "field1" },
        { "data": "field2" },
        { "data": "field3" }
    ]
});
```

You should match the table columns with the **columns** array.

That's it!